# What is the best way to install a shower curtain when one wall is sloped

Tags: bathroom, shower

I have a converted attic bedroom with a bathroom.  I want to install a curtain rod, but one side of the rod has to connect to a sloped wall (the roof). What would be the best way to install a rod in this scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get a swivel shower rod flange like this:

[image: Picture of a bright brass swivel shower rod flange]

or this:

[image: Picture of a satin chrome swivel anchor]

It looks like they're available in a range of sizes and finishes so you should be able to find one you like.

Comment: One of the problems with this is you still have a gap between the wall/roof and curtain, and you could have water splashing out, depending on how far out the shower head is aimed.

Comment: I am removing both links as they are broken (404). I did a reverse image search and couldn't find new links on Signature Hardware.

Comment: I did find another one by doing a web search for "swivel shower rod flange" like you suggested though so that seems like good advice that won't result in 404s.

Answer (score 8):

At my parent's cottage, they had a similar situation. The tub comes out from the sloped wall, with the shower head on the opposite wall.

They put a corrugated translucent acrylic panel up, cut to fit under the sloped part of the wall, and framed using some PVC c-channel moulding all the way around (you can find all of this at most box stores). The panel is about half the length of the tub.

Then there is a normal (but short) shower rod and curtain up on the other half, which works out to be more or less the same height as a normal shower curtain. As I recall, it's about half the length of the tub (so 2.5') which is comfortable to get in and out of. Some caulking around all the moulding on the inside, and it actually works very well, and looks pretty decent.

[image]

[image]

---

Update: Was out there again this weekend, and remembered to take a pic. somewhat low quality as I just had my iPod:

[image]

Comment: This is definitely a good idea.  In my situation though the rod extends past the tub and there is tiling at the foot of the tub extending to the wall (at the height of the tub).  I would probably have to put the shower head in a pretty extreme position for it to get through the gap you mentioned above.  For my situation it is likely that the swivel connector will be good enough, though this solution might be the best for most other.

Comment: This is a really neat solution. Can you expand on where you got the materials? "corrugated translucent acrylic panel up"
When I search this it comes up with $500 acrylic boards for covering a patio and such. I don't think this is the same thing? "PVC c-channel moulding"
This seems easier to find, but when you say "box store" do you mean something like UPS?

Answer (score 0):

Depending what material your curtain rod is made out of, cut the end of the rod at an angle. Do a small angle first and work your way to what will line up with your wall. Since the rod width is not changing the end cap should still work on a slant.