# What glass and materials are needed to install a glass shower screen against a sloped wall and where can I get them?

Tags: shower

[image: sloped shower]

I saw a picture in [an answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/4981/33) to [a question from 3/6/11](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/4966/33) about installing a shower curtain with a sloped ceiling.  There was a piece of "glass" installed on the sloped side (left) and a shower curtain on the right.  I was wondering if it was in fact glass the was specially cut or something that you made yourself.  We have this problem and are looking for a solution just like this.

Comment: @gregmac a little help here.

Comment: Maybe this question should be a comment on the original answer since it seems that it will only result in a "where do I get this glass" type answer?

Comment: @Steven - I made an edit to that effect. I think this question stands on its own. Perhaps it is even more general. How does one go about building or buying something other than a rectangular glass shower enclosure? Is it custom or are there some off-the-shelf options?

Answer (score 1):

Glass in a shower enclosure must be [tempered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toughened_glass) to be safe. Tempered (or toughened) glass is much harder to break than conventional glass and, if broken, crumbles into pieces that are not very sharp.

Because it is so hard, tempered glass is cut to size *before* it is tempered (hardened). This is almost always done by a specialty glass shop.  Usually they will either take your measurements or come and measure themselves, and then create the sized tempered piece.

There are also various plastics that are used in shower enclosures that are also less prone to breaking than ordinary glass. Some of these may be able to be cut by the DIYer.

In either case, you need to be sure there is a good, waterproof seal between the panel and the wall and tub.

Comment: What should I do to make sure the seal is good and waterproof?

Answer (score 0):

In the answer I specifically mentioned it is corrugated translucent acrylic in a PVC c-channel trim.

[image]

These materials are almost certainly available at your local big box hardware store.