# What materials can be used for moving shower walls?

Tags: shower, materials

I am currently thinking about a good shower solution for a very small, very old flat. As it is so small and in the top floor (hence: problems with the pitch of the roof, like [on this image](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/37774/what-glass-and-materials-are-needed-to-install-a-glass-shower-screen-against-a-s)) I cannot use any standard shower cabins. So I think about building the shower cabin partly by myself.

I imagine two big glass plates, where one is at a fixed position (200cm x 80cm) and the other one is able to move (200cm x 90cm, where a corner is removed because of the roof).

However, I worry because a 200cm x 90cm glass plate is very heavy. I am not a craftsman and I think more can go wrong when you have to deal with that weight.

Hence my question: Is there any other material besides glass that I can use for such a movable shower wall?

I thought about acrylic glass or other plastic. What are the disadvantages of those materials? How do you cut a streight edge of the [whatever you suggest]?

This is my bathroom (its also the kitchen ... :-/):

[image]

Comment: English is not my mother tongue. If you see any errors, please add a comment or edit my post.